# Underlined text in forms

Tags: html, browser, textarea, spell-checking

I have noticed that if the user do not write correct English in a form, words get underlined in red. The problem comes when people writes correct French or any other language that is not English, it gets underlined too. How to control this? I mean, how to control the input language or at least that never underline.

For instance in this form: http://jsfiddle.net/wxrJP/
if you write maison a red line appears.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <textarea id="normal" name="text"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: That’s up to the user’s browser – whether or not they have installed spelling correction at all, and which language they have set it to. Unless a browser choses the right language dictionary based on page language automatically, there’s nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That has noting to do with `Your Spellcheck`, that's about the browser of the user. If the Browser has a Greek Spellcheck, well than everything will be underlined.

You don't have to do anything about this.

Comment: I do not see how to change the browser language preferences in Safari or Firefox for instance Perhaps you mean that this depends of the system preferences of the hole computer?

Comment: On every browser they are Spell Check Libraries, on safari, as well as Firefox. A user in Germany for example can have his German spell check activated. Then all is underlined in red when he writes English.

Answer (score 0):

Use `spellcheck="false"` on your `textarea` to turn off the spell check.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wxrJP/2/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/wxrJP/4/) (Compare, just **focus** both the fields one by one, and you will see 1st one won't underline where the next one will)

---

As you commented(Sorry I missed that out in the question that you wanted to give preference to lang specific spell check first),so I won't agree with the answer below and the comment, you can control spell check for specific language using `lang` attribute.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wxrJP/5/) (Focus the fields one by one and see the difference)

Comment: To remove completely It works perfect. Thank you. Is there any way that I can control that a specific form spellcheck for instance in Franch

Comment: It seems to work if you put the value, but not if the user enter text in french